# Setting a multi-valued parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, struts

When I submit a form in HTML, I can pass a parameter multiple times, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4">
```

Then in struts I can have a bean with property String[] id, and it'll populate the array correctly.

My question is, how can I do that in Javascript? When I have an array, and I set form.id.value = myArray, it just sets the value to a comma-separated list. So then on the Struts end, I just get one-element array, i.e. the String "2,4".

I should add, I need to submit this in a form, so I can't just generate a GET request, e.g. id=2&id=4.

Comment: So you're dynamically generating these inputs via javascript?

Comment: Well, partly. The inputs are set in the HTML based on the values from the previous submit, but then I need to change them on the next submit, by getting the values out of a javascript object. There may be more or less parameters compared to the previous submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  It generates a hidden form field for each element of a JavaScript array:

```
var el;
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length) {
    el = document.createElement("input");
    el.type = "hidden";
    el.name = "id";
    el.value = myArray[i];

    // Optional: give each input an id so they can easily be accessed individually:
    el.id = "hidden-myArray-" + i;

    // Optional: give all inputs a class so they can easily be accessed as a group:
    el.className = "hidden-myArray";

    form.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I just had to add a part to delete the old elements from the previous submit before creating the new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Not positive what you're trying to do but here's a go:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('id');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    input.value = myArray[i];
}
```

That iterates over all the inputs with name '`id`' and assigns the corresponding value from myArray.

You better be sure `myArray.length == document.getElementsByName('id').length`

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what I needed. I had to take a slightly more complicated approach though, deleting the old elements first and then generating new ones, since I couldn't ensure that the lengths would be equal.

Comment: breaks if there are elements with the same name in other forms (or elsewhere) on the page; it's better to use form.elements to access the specific form...

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to give each input a unique ID:-

```
<input id="id1" type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
<input id="id2" type="hidden" name="id" value="4">
```

Then in javascript:-

```
document.getElementById("id1").value = myArray[0];
document.getElementById("id2").value = myArray[1];
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for the idea. This approach will work, but the problem is that I will have to generate the elements dynamically since I don't know how many there will be prior to submitting the form. It will work, but I prefer a cleaner solution if there is one.

Comment: It looks like I did have to create the elements dynamically after all. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: In that case add this detail to the text of your question, that makes the accepted answer match the question better.

Answer (score 1):

`forms[0].elements.theName` contains a collections of all elements with name-attribute 'theName'. Example:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="test"><br>
<input type="text" name="test">
</form>
<script>
var values = ['foo', 'bar'];
var testElements = document.forms[0].elements.test;
for(var i = 0; i < testElements.length; ++i)
    testElements[i].value = values[i];
</script>
```